# How can I dynamically update widget text using "latest" best Kotlin Android pratcices?

Tags: android, kotlin

I created a new Kotlin project in the latest version of Android Studio, using the empty activity project template, which only contains a TextView with "Hello, World!" in its main layout.  Then:

1. I enabled `viewBinding` in the module `build.gradle`.
2. Defined `binding` in `MainActivity.kt` (as shown in the last listing).
3. Gave that TextView an identifier `txt_hello` as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<...>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtHello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</...>
```

Then I went on to `MainActivity.kt` file to define some code that modifies the `text` attribute of the `txt_hellow` `TextView` widget as follows:

```kotlin
package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

// I added this:
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // I removed this:
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // I added this:
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.txtHello.setOnClickListener {
            binding.txtHello.setText("lel")
        }
    }
}
```

But, I get the following error:

> String literal in `setText` can not be translated. Use Android resources instead.

How can I update widgets using the `viewBinding` approach?

Comment: See the code example here. You skipped a couple of steps in your activity code, and you no longer should use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`. Look carefully at what they have in their `onCreate()`. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#activities

Comment: @Tenfour04 - I updated the code.  Still same error.  Care to point out what are the missing steps?

Comment: You got that part right now. I wasn't commenting about your error (which is not actually an error but only a warning). That's a separate issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I think that's a warning that you shouldn't use a hardcoded string in the text view, because it's a bad practice and cannot be translated.

So you have to create some string values in your **strings.xml**, for example:

```
<string name="text_hello">Hello</string>
```

And use that string value like this

```
binding.txtHello.text = getText(R.string.text_hello)
```

Comment: I guess that requires to statically write the text in `strings.xml`?  But what if we want to dynamically update the text?

Comment: If your text isn't in a speakable language that would need to be translated, you can  just ignore the warning. If your text has a mixture of words and numbers that you fill in, you can use string formatting with your string resource.

Comment: @caveman actually you just can directly assign it to the `binding.txtHello.text` if your string is not hardcoded. Example if you have an edittext you could assign it like : `binding.txtHello.text = binding.yourEditText.text.toString()`

Comment: Would it be a better solution if I use placeholders in named strings in `strings.xml` so that, when I use them in Kotlin codes, I dynamically change them?  How will this affect translate-ability?  And is this a recommended approach?

Comment: that's a great solution if you just want to dynamically change some words in a string template

Answer (score 1):

That error is because you can't use  `binding.txtHello.text = "lel"`  The reason for this is that there are two definitions of setText-  one for a string and one for an int (a text resource).  This means the code that converts setters from Java to Kotlin doesn't know which to call when you try to assign to the text variable, so it throws this error.  Instead, use binding.txtHell.setText("lel").  You need to do this whenever there are multiple functions named setXXX for a given XXX written in Java.

Comment: Done, code updated.  But still the same error, plus one more `Use of setter method instead of property access syntax`.